# X-axis label for iOS-Charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am putting dates on the x-axis of a bar chart, which is working fine.  However, I want to put the weekday on top with the corresponding date below  on a new line. How can I achieve this? This is my code so far:

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE:dd"

 let today = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
 today.uppercaseString
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

x axis label supports word wrapping. you can override drawLabels to get what you want.

What you can try is carefully set the label's width, so it can automatically wrap it for you.

You can check out x axis renderer's `computeAxis()` method, and properly override it. It calculates the label's width, height, etc there.